# How to inject angular directive such as ng-dblclick to all the specified HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to have a global handler for all the ng-dblclick occured from button, and input type="submit". How do i achieve this behaviour, by specifying and inject it in app.init.js file?

Thank you

Comment: This can be done by creating a directive and placing it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular directive to catch click or dbclick event

```
app.directive("ngdblclick", ['$compile', function($compile){
'use strict'
return{
    compile : function(elements, attributes){
        return{
            restrict: 'C',
            post : function(scope, element, attribute){
                var isSingleClick = true;
                element.bind('click', function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        if(isSingleClick){
                            console.log("It's a single click");
                            return;
                        }
                    }, 500);
                });

                element.bind('dblclick', function(){
                    console.log("It's a double click");
                    isSingleClick = false;
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        isSingleClick = true;
                        return;
                    }, 500);
                });
            }
        };
    }
 };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a custom directive that will extract all its child elements(in this case `buttons` and `input` type *submit*) and adds the `ng-dblclick` directive to them:

Look at the below example:

**Example#1 :**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', MyController)
  .directive('globalDblClick', globalDblClickDirective);

function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.times = 0;
  $scope.globalDblClick = function() {
    $scope.times++;
  };
}

function globalDblClickDirective($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      globalDblClick: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

      elem.find('button').each(function(index, btnElem) {
        btnElem = angular.element(btnElem);
        btnElem.attr('ng-dblclick', attr.globalDblClick);
        $compile(btnElem)(scope);
      });

      elem.find('input[type="submit"]').each(function(index, inpElem) {
        inpElem = angular.element(inpElem);
        inpElem.attr('ng-dblclick', attr.globalDblClick);
        $compile(inpElem)(scope);
      });
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

  <section global-dbl-click="globalDblClick()">

    <button>Click Me Twice</button>

    <input type="submit" value="Double Click Me" />

    <input type="text" value="Won't work here" />

    <div> DoubledClicked: {{times}} times </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

If you want to manually add; You can write a custom directive that you can use in place of `ng-dblclick` and internally it will add `ng-dblclick` directive if the type is `button` or `input` of type *submit*.
**Note: Below example is just for the demonstration of the above concept in reality, you wouldn't use this as you can directly use `ng-dblclick`.**

Check the below example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', MyController)
  .directive('globalDblClick', globalDblClickDirective);

function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.times = 0;
  $scope.globalDblClick = function() {
    $scope.times++;
  };
}

function globalDblClickDirective($compile) {
  return {
    priority: 1001, // compiles first
    terminal: true, // prevent lower priority directives to compile after it
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      globalDblClick: '&'
    },
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {

      if (tElement.is('button') || tElement.is('input[type="submit"]')) {
        tElement.removeAttr('global-dbl-click'); // to avoid infinite compile loop

        tElement.attr('ng-dblclick', tAttrs.globalDblClick);
        var linkFn = $compile(tElement);

        return function(scope) {
          linkFn(scope);
        };
      }
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

  <button class="dblClick" global-dbl-click="globalDblClick()">Click Me Twice</button>

  <input type="submit" class="dblClick" global-dbl-click="globalDblClick()" value="Double Click Me" />

  <span> DoubledClicked: {{times}} times </span>

</div>
```